# Marker Google Maps Android Auto Hide/Show

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markers

I'm developing map with lots of markers using Google Maps API. This is my drawmarker function:

```
    //Draw marker to google map
private void drawMarker(LatLng point,String title,String snipped){
    Marker marker=mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(title)
            .snippet(snipped)
            .position(point));
}
```

And override Onconnected:

```
    @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    //Get Last Know Location
    mLastLocation=LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection Success");
    if(mLastLocation!=null){
        curLatLng=new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        //Get All Wifi to Draw to Google Map
        allListWifi=data.getAllLocations();
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(curLatLng, 17));
        for(int j=0;j<allListWifi.size();j++){
            //Item wifi
            LatLng desLatLng=new LatLng(Double.valueOf(allListWifi.get(j).get("LAT")), Double.valueOf(allListWifi.get(j).get("LNG")));
            int distance=Math.round(distancePoints(curLatLng, desLatLng));
            drawMarker(desLatLng, String.valueOf(allListWifi.get(j).get("NAME")), String.valueOf(distance));
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And problem is : 1/ my app spends a lot of time to draw markers on google map and my app is so delay. Then i think just draw only markers on curent screen map which i'm seeing.When i move the map the new markers will appear and the old markers will disappear.
2/ I want to gather adjacent locations in a group as I zoom out and they detach automatically as I zoom in.
3/ Thank you very much. Have a nice day everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the `OnCameraChangeListner()`. You can check if a `MarkOption` is within you visible region in the `onCameraChange()` method.

Sample Code:

```
        final List<MarkerOptions> markerOptions = new ArrayList<MarkerOptions>();
        markerOptions.add(markerOne);
        markerOptions.add(markerTwo);

        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
                for (MarkerOptions option : markerOptions) {
                    if (bounds.contains(option.getPosition())) {
                        mMap.addMarker(option);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```